# Why can't Sequel Pro connect to my local XAMPP server on Catalina?

Tags: xampp, localhost, macos-catalina, sequelpro

I'm trying to set up my first XAMPP server. Most recent version of XAMPP, Catalina 10.15.3. XAMPP seems to run ok, I have Apache and mySQL on. Doesn't seem to work at localhost default, but I selected the option to run at localhost:8080 and when I visit that url I see the sample site.

BUT when I try to connect with Sequel Pro using host: 127.0.0.1, username root, port 8080 it thinks for a minute (vs. instant failure with no port specified) then times out. Have restarted my computer, but no luck. Any clues?

Comment: Also tried MAMP and same thing is happening...MAMP starts a server that I can access in the browser, but Sequel Pro times out connecting to the same port. Tried username root with blank password and password root.

Comment: ETA: Have now figured out that with MAMP for some reason even though the server is generally setting itself to port 8888, I need to go to 8889 to connect to SQL. So, that's mysteriously working! But I'd still like to get XAMPP working, and if I need a different port number there, I can't figure out what it is.